# Update multiple fields(columns) in a document with VB.net and MONGODB

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I have a collection with the fields(column) like "name" and "lastname", so i would like to update those fields(column) at the same time.
I have the next code to update only one field(column).

```
Dim fltr = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of String)("name", t_update.Text.Trim)
collection.UpdateMany(fltr, New BsonDocument("name", t_name.Text.Trim))
```

Comment: are you looking for `Update data in  MONGODB` ??

Comment: @zackraiyan yes, update multiple columns in a document using vb.net. Actually, I have just solved it. I post my answer below. If you have another way, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by using the method ADD(field, value). There is more information and tutorials with C#, that is why it is not easy to do it with VB.net.

```
collection.UpdateMany(fltr, New BsonDocument("$set", New BsonDocument("name", t_name.Text.Trim).Add("lastname", t_lastname.Text.Trim)))r
```